# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'main' is not defined SQLlite3

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to upload the id of the users onto the database using sqllite however whenever i run the code and execute the command it shows this error

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'main' is not defined

```
    async def add(self, ctx, user:discord.User):
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = main.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT Players FROM main")
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if result != user.id:
                sql = ("INSERT INTO main(Players) VALUES(?)")
                val = (user.id)
                await ctx.send(f"<@!{user.id}> has been added")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"<@{user.id}> is already in teh database")
            cursor.execute(sql,val)
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
```

Comment: Where did you define `main`?

Comment: main is the name of the sql file

Comment: Did you import it or something? Im pretty sure the error speaks for itself, it's not defined